# vf page Selected Accounts show in different window as PDF

Tags: visualforce

I have a vf page with datatable view, when user select few accounts from that view and click commandButton, he need to get that in pdf in different window.

Comment: google renderas in salesforce, you would get a direct code on how to render a VF page as PDF.

Comment: thanks Rao, RenderAs is easy, but my situation is bit different. I have a page with list of account shown as datatable view in vf page. When user select few from that list only the selected accounts need to be passed to the new window and open as pdf. How to retain the selected values and pass to new window page.

Comment: can you share your page and controller, its an easy fix if you have already taken care of getting the accounts selected by the user part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a wrapper class. Create a wrapper class (`accountwrapper`) with Account and boolean value. Render the Boolean value as a checkbox in VF page so that user can select the accounts. Pass the selected Accounts to a VF page to render as PDF. Hope this helps.

VF Page for selecting accounts

```
<apex:page controller="AccountClass" tabStyle="Account" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts with CheckBoxes">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="List of Available Accounts" collapsible="false">
                <apex:dataTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" border="1" cellpadding="4" columnsWidth="100px">
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}">
                            <!-- <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!GetSelected}"/>-->
                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!a.acc.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Account Number" value="{!a.acc.AccountNumber}" />
                    <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!a.acc.Phone}" />
                </apex:dataTable>               
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandLink action="{!printPDF}" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Print Selected Accounts"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

VF page for printing PDF

```
<apex:page controller="AccountClass" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts">
        <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Selected Accounts" collapsible="false">
            <apex:dataTable value="{!SelectedAccounts}" var="s" columnswidth="100px" cellpadding="4" border="1">
                <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!s.Name}" />
                <apex:column headervalue="Account Number" value="{!s.AccountNumber}" />
                <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!s.Phone}" />
            </apex:dataTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class AccountClass {
    List<accountwrapper> accountList = new List<accountwrapper>();
    List<Account> selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();
    public List<accountwrapper> getAccounts(){
        List<Account> allActs = [select Id, Name, AccountNumber, Phone from Account limit 5];
        for(Account a : allActs){
            accountList.add(new accountwrapper(a));
        }
        return accountList;
    }
    public List<Account> GetSelectedAccounts(){
        if(selectedAccounts.size()>0){
            return selectedAccounts;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    public PageReference getSelected(){
        selectedAccounts.clear();
        for(accountwrapper accwrapper : accountList){
            if(accwrapper.selected == true){
                selectedAccounts.add(accwrapper.acc);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference printPDF(){
        selectedAccounts.clear();
        for(accountwrapper accwrapper : accountList){
            if(accwrapper.selected == true){
                selectedAccounts.add(accwrapper.acc);
            }
        }
        PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference('/apex/accountspdf');
        //pdfPage.setRedirect(true);
        return pdfPage;
    }    
    public class accountwrapper{
        public Account acc{get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public accountwrapper(Account a){
            acc = a;
            selected = false;
        }
    }    
}
```