# Open Visualforce page as pdf in a different tab without downloading pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, pdf, onclickjavascript

I have a requirement to open a pdf in a different tab in same window on click of a button on a visualforce page.Currently in the system - Chrome HTML Document (.pdf) is getting downloaded.

Current implementation of vf page 1(where sumit button is placed) is:-

```
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >   
            <apex:actionFunction name="openNewPage" action="{!GeneratePDFpage}" status="openNewPage"  rerender="panel,userMessages" />
            <apex:commandButton id="sbtn" value="submit" onclick="openNewPage(); " rerender="none"/> 
            
            <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function popupnewwindow()
                    {
                        var url  = '{!urlFromApex}';
                        var newWin1 = window.open(url, 'url','height=80,width=600,left=100,resizable=yes,top=100,scrollbars=yes');
                        window.history.back();
                    }
                </script>
                <apex:actionStatus onstop="(popupnewwindow())" id="openNewPage" >
                </apex:actionStatus>            
            </apex:outputPanel> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Apex class:-

//URL Gnerator method

```
    public void GeneratePDFpage()
       {    
       
                PageReference  pageRef;
                pageRef = Page.pdfVFPageToDisplay;
                pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', g_Id);
                pageRef.getParameters().put('inBRS', string.valueof(IsBRS));//parameter 1
                pageRef.getParameters().put('inSummary', string.valueof(IsSummary));//parameter 2
                urlFromApex =  pageRef.getUrl();// tried pageref.setredirect=true;

        }
```

Visualforce page(vf page 2- which opens on click of submit button page 1) for pdf:-

Header:-

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ControllerExtension" 
      showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
       applyhtmltag="false" standardstylesheets="false" renderAs="PDF" 
     contentType="application/pdf#{!Account.id}.pdf">
     </apex:page>
```

What have I tried:-

1. Moving away from commanddbutton to commandlink to utilize target=blank attribute
2. Using simple window.open() to avoid any pop up and open in a new tab.
3. File Upload and Download Security - changed pdf and html to execute in browser from download

   ```
        <apex:actionFunction name="openNewPage" action="{!GeneratePDFpage}" status="openNewPage"  rerender="panel,userMessages" />
        <!--<apex:commandButton id="sbtn" value="submit" onclick="openNewPage(); " rerender="none"/> -->
            <apex:commandLink id="sbtn" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" value="submit" onclick="openNewPage();" target="_blank"/>
      <script>
      function popupnewwindow()
                    {
                        var url  = '{!urlFromApex}';
                        window.open(url);//https://bearOrg--dev--c.sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/pdfVFPageToDisplay?Id=0010SALESFORCE&inBRS=true&inSummary=false
                        window.history.back();
                    }
       <apex:actionStatus onstop="(popupnewwindow())" id="openNewPage" >
                  </apex:actionStatus>
   ```

What have I achieved:-

1. pdf getting downloaded in seperate tab **but NOT OPENING by default**.
2. Note :- vf page 1 remains open but as a standalone page not within app.

Where I need help:-

1. Open vf page 2 i.e. pdf instead of downloading it in a new tab of same window.
2. PDF should open standalone(preferred)/ within the app.

I have a similar requirement implemented where a vf page with renderAsPDF is called using window.open() from lwc. Here it opens in a new tab with pdf already open by default:-

```
 navigateToVFPage() {
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: `/apex/vfPagePDF?id=${this.recId}`
        }
    }).then(vfURL => {
    window.open(vfURL, "_blank");
   //vfURL = https://bearOrg--dev.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/webpage/%2Fapex%2FvfPagePDF%3Fid%3D001oSALESFORCE%26lang%3Den-CA
    this.closeQuickAction();
    });
```

Note- A noticable difference in url getting generated from vf /lwc.

Links I have referred to solve this issue:-
Doc link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm

1. [vf page Selected Accounts show in different window as PDF](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94853/vf-page-selected-accounts-show-in-different-window-as-pdf)
2. [open pdf in new tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80771/open-pdf-in-new-tab)
3. [Salesforce open PDF in new tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/304946/salesforce-open-pdf-in-new-tab?rq=1)
4. [Open PDF in browser instead of Downloading](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154695/open-pdf-in-browser-instead-of-downloading)
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser
6. [Creating a VF that redirects to another URL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187843/creating-a-vf-that-redirects-to-another-url)

Comment: Not all browsers can view PDFs inline. Also, why not just show the Visualforce page in normal HTML form, and provide a download button to get a PDF version?